# A metric space is compact iff every closed ball is compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Is this true? I think I have a counter example. If we consider the set $(\mathbb{N},d)$, where $d$ is the discrete metric, then every subset closed ball is compact, but since $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite $(\mathbb{N},d)$ is not compact.

Comment: Every closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact.

Comment: Does it only hold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then?

Comment: Well it should, since every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and bounded. Since every ball is closed and bounded, the result follows.

Comment: Forgive me, of course they aren't. They're not bounded.

Comment: Note that your statement is true if you replace closed ball by closed set.

Comment: There is a concept of "proper" metric spaces for which closed and bounded balls are compact.

Comment: @egreg: No, it's not: For any set $X$ with the discrete metric, and for any $x \in X$, the closed ball with radius $1$ around $x$ is $X$, so if every closed ball is compact, then $X$ is obviously compact.

Comment: @dankness You're right!